# mysql rows in individual rows

Tags: php, html, css, row

i have a litte problem! i want to fetch the last 3 rows from my mysql database.. (works)

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id,title,description FROM news ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 3";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
?>
    <div class="one-of-three">
        <div class="box">
            <h2><?PHP echo ($list['id']);?> <?PHP echo (htmlentities($list['title'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));?></h2>
            <div class="content clearfix">
                <p><?PHP echo (htmlentities($list['description'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

my problem is the html layout! i have 3 div boxes wich i will float..

```
    <div class="one-of-three">
        [...]
    </div>
    <div class="two-of-three">
        [...]
    </div>
    <div class="three-of-three">
        [...]
    </div>
```

but my result gives me

```
    <div class="one-of-three">
        [...]
    </div>
    <div class="one-of-three">
        [...]
    </div>
    <div class="one-of-three">
        [...]
    </div>
```

i tried different things but i dont how it works :( 
you can give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably get an array `$numbers = array('one', 'two', 'three');`. Then have a variable `$i = 0;` and increment it in the loop. The first line should then be like: `<div class="<?php echo $numbers[$i++]; ?>-of-three">`.

Comment: $numbers = array('one', 'two', 'three');
 $i = 0;
 while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 {
 ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $numbers[$i++]; ?>-of-three">

Comment: Oh yeah oops, fixed it :D Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $n = array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three');
 while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
    <div class="<?php echo $n[$list['id']]; ?>-of-three">
```